# updateLayer() context

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics

In an NSView, am doing this for macOS 10.14:

```
override var wantsUpdateLayer: Bool {
    return true
}

override func updateLayer() {
    if let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext {
        // Never enters here
    }
    else {
        // Gives run-time error, invalid context
        let path = NSBezierPath()
        path.move(to: NSPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.line(to: NSPoint(x: 10, y: 10))
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

So, there's no valid graphics context as there is in override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect), and I cannot seem to obtain one.  How I am supposed to obtain a valid graphics context for drawing in updateLayer?

Comment: I assume it could have something to do with self.layer?, but to me the official documentation is very much incomplete and seems like it's necessary to resort to trial-and-error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not supposed to be drawing in `updateLayer`, which is why there is no `cgContext` passed to you.  Implement `CALayerDelegate`'s  `drawLayer:inContext:` for that. `updateLayer` is an alternate method for assigning a bitmap directly to the layer, and is limited to that.

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/SettingUpLayerObjects/SettingUpLayerObjects.html

Comment: BTW, thank you for a quick and concise answer.  I suppose Apple should change the name from updateLayer() to updateLayerBackgroundOrBitmapAndThatsAll().

Comment: You're welcome!  It is not the best method name, certainly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution for Swift 5:

```
override var wantsUpdateLayer: Bool
{ 
    return (true)
}

override func updateLayer ()
{
    let cgimage: CGImage? = picture // Here comes the picture
    if cgimage != nil
    {
        let nsimage: NSImage? = NSImage(cgImage: cgimage!, size: NSZeroSize)
        if nsimage != nil
        {
            let desiredScaleFactor: CGFloat? = self.window?.backingScaleFactor
            if desiredScaleFactor != nil
            {
                let actualScaleFactor: CGFloat? = nsimage!.recommendedLayerContentsScale(desiredScaleFactor!)
                if actualScaleFactor != nil
                {
                    self.layer!.contents      = nsimage!.layerContents(forContentsScale: actualScaleFactor!)
                    self.layer!.contentsScale = actualScaleFactor!
                }
            }
        
        }
    }
}
```

You see where the picture is inserted and later assigned. Hope that helps. I had the same problem. Much quicker than the draw() func.